# Почему Map работает быстрее чем switch со строками?

Tags: java, производительность

Я накидал тестовый код для проверки скорости работы swich с разными типами данных.
То что все типы данных работают около 12 сек, а  string работает дольше в два раза(22 сек) - ок. Но почему работа string в HashMap занимает 11 сек?

Тут два непонятных момента - почему HashMap работает так быстро относительно switch и почему switch работает так медленно относительно HashMap?

Код: https://pastebin.com/FCeQiEXd

П.С. если хотите лично протестировать, то нужно заменить в randChoiseGenerator массив и метод. 
П.П.С. конструкция if-else работает те же 12 секунд, хотя switch 21.. тоже странно с двух сторон сразу

Comment: возможно дело в хешфункции, у которой результат - получение адреса памяти вашего стринга. Поэтому сложность o(1). поэтому вся моментальность в этом и кроется

Comment: но ведь у switch тоже должно использоваться хеширование?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это объясняется тем, что switch по строке компилируется в довольно громоздкую конструкцию.

Возможность свитчевать по строке в Java 7 добавили только на уровне компилятора, не добавляя новых байткодов и не изменяя поведения виртуальной машины. Поэтому на уровне байткода свитч всё ещё существует только для чисел. Но свитч не может быть неточным, а хэши строк могут и совпадать. Поэтому этот пример

```
public int simpleSwitch(String value) {
    switch (value) {
        case "a":
            return 0;
        case "b":
            return 2;
        case "c":
            return 3;
        default:
            return 4;
    }
}
```

будет скомпилирован в такой байткод

```
 0: aload_1
 1: astore_2
 2: iconst_m1
 3: istore_3
 4: aload_2
 5: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I
 8: tableswitch   {
         default: 75
             min: 97
             max: 99
              97: 36
              98: 50
              99: 64
       }
36: aload_2
37: ldc           #3                  // String a
39: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
42: ifeq          75
45: iconst_0
46: istore_3
47: goto          75
50: aload_2
51: ldc           #5                  // String b
53: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
56: ifeq          75
59: iconst_1
60: istore_3
61: goto          75
64: aload_2
65: ldc           #6                  // String c
67: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
70: ifeq          75
73: iconst_2
74: istore_3
75: iload_3
76: tableswitch   {
         default: 110
             min: 0
             max: 2
               0: 104
               1: 106
               2: 108
       }
104: iconst_0
105: ireturn
106: iconst_2
107: ireturn
108: iconst_3
109: ireturn
110: iconst_4
111: ireturn
```

Как можно увидеть, сначала делается свитч по хэшкоду, потом вызов метода equals и потом ещё один свитч по его результатам. Причём, если диапазон хэшкодов строк в кейсах будет разреженным, вместо быстрой инструкции `tableswitch` будет использована медленная `lookupswitch`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но тут разведал одну штуку - 12 секунд выполнения - это просто время вызова метода) То есть если убрать свитч из метода то время выполнения остается таким же. 
Проявилась часть умственных способностей JVM(а может и компилятора?) - если ни одно из передающихся в свитч значений не совпадает с кейсами, то JVM начинает игнорировать свитч и время выполнения снова становится равным 12 сек